# yii saving multiple attribute values of one posted array

Tags: php, html, yii

Hello I have Following input

```
   <div class="span" >
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'name[]'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'designation[]'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'contact_number[]'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'email_id[]'); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'name[]', array('')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'designation[]'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'contact_number[]'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'email_id[]'); ?>
    </div>
```

It posts following data

Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => p1
            [1] => b1
        )

```
[designation] => Array
    (
        [0] => gjhgjj
        [1] => jhbjbb
    )

[contact_number] => Array
    (
        [0] => 878978
        [1] => 8897897
    )

[email_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => bjhhhjk
        [1] => mnbnn
    )
```

)

How can I save it to $model->attributes?? 
I have tried this

```
        foreach ($_POST['Contacts'] as $key=>$value){

                foreach ($_POST['Contacts'][$key] as $val ){                                                
                    $contactModel = new Contacts;   
                    $contactModel->$key = $val;     
                    $contactModel->save();              
                }                   
                $contactModel->save();
            }
```

But It doesnt save. Please Help.

Comment: foreach ($_POST['Contacts'] as $key=>$value){ 
     
     foreach ($_POST['Contacts'][$key] as $k) {
      $contactModel = new Contacts;      
      $contactModel->$key=$k;
      $contactModel->property_id = $_POST['CommercialProperty']['property_id'];
      $contactModel->added_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $contactModel->save();
     }    
    } saves only one attribute value and not other

Comment: I have found solution!

Answer (score 0):

> can you try this code snippet.

```
    if(isset($_POST['Contacts'])){
        foreach($_POST['Contacts'] as $ContactModels){
            $ContactModels[]=new Contacts;
        }
        foreach($ContactModels as $i=>$ContactModel){
            if(isset($_POST['Contacts'][$i])){
                $ContactModel->attributes=$_POST['Contacts'][$i];
                $ContactModel->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the brackets in front of the attribute name and give it an index:

```
<div class="span" >
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[0]name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[0]designation'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[0]contact_number'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[0]email_id'); ?>

</div>
<div class="span3">
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[1]name', array('')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[1]designation'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[1]contact_number'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($contactModel,'[1]email_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Then you can just loop through with foreach:

```
foreach($_POST['Contacts'] as $attributes) {
    $contactModel = new Contacts;
    $contactModel->attrbutes = $attributes;
    $contactModel->save();
}
```

If you have existing models you can use their id as index and find and save the correct model that way.

Comment: Nope.. Its not saving. If I do print_r($_POST['Contacts']) in controller, I get Array ( [name] => a1 [designation] => hjbh [contact_number] => 67576576 [email_id] => 7987 ).

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode it to a string before saving the array. Controller code:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['Objekte']['attribute']))
    {
        if(is_array($_REQUEST['Objekte']['attribute']))
        {
            $model->attribute = json_encode($_REQUEST['Objekte']['attribute']);
        }
    }

    // now save
```